# Other error occurred: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) #1

Tags: python

I am having an issue with the API that I wrote. Am having an error with Json which I find it weird. The overall idea is to search for a bunch of VINs and store it into a Json file. The code works to a point until I store the First VIN then on the 2nd one it works however I get the error in the title. I do know what am doing wrong that seems like the issue is saving the data. Please find the code below.

api.py

```
import requests
import json
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
#Define The VINs Lists
VINs = ['KPTGOC1FSCP300549', '5J6RM3H53CL015747', 'TDSY61U032248', 'JDAJ210GOO1052908', 'KNAKH812BA7683150', 'jtmbh31v806052793', 'Kmhsh81gdcu864966' ]

try:
    with open('vins.json', 'w') as f:
        for vin in VINs:
            response = requests.get(f'https://vindecodervehicle.com/api/v1/?id=xxxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx&vin={vin}')
            response.raise_for_status()
            # access JSOn content
            jsonResponse = response.json()
            #Create the json File.
            json.dump(jsonResponse, f, indent=4)
            print("Entire JSON response")
            print(jsonResponse)

except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
```

The Vins file which is being store.
vins.json

```
{
    "data": {
        "matchingManufacturers": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "manuId": 175,
                    "manuName": "SSANGYONG"
                }
            ]
        },
        "matchingModels": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "manuId": 175,
                    "modelId": 5000,
                    "modelName": "REXTON / REXTON II (GAB_)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "matchingVehicles": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "manuId": 175,
                    "modelId": 5000,
                    "carId": 18259,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.7 Xdi",
                    "carName": "SSANGYONG REXTON / REXTON II (GAB_) 2.7 Xdi"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 175,
                    "modelId": 5000,
                    "carId": 27999,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.7 D 4x4",
                    "carName": "SSANGYONG REXTON / REXTON II (GAB_) 2.7 D 4x4"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 175,
                    "modelId": 5000,
                    "carId": 28000,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.7 Xdi",
                    "carName": "SSANGYONG REXTON / REXTON II (GAB_) 2.7 Xdi"
                }
            ]
        },
        "matchingVehiclesCount": 3,
        "dataSource": [
            {
                "dataSourceKey": "vin_filter"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 200
} {
    "data": {
        "matchingManufacturers": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "manuName": "HONDA"
                }
            ]
        },
        "matchingModels": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "modelName": "CR-V IV (RM_)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "matchingVehicles": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 6978,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.0",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.0"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 6980,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 7980,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 AWD",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 AWD"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 55240,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 AWD",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 AWD"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 56243,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.0 iVtec (RE5, RM1)",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.0 iVtec (RE5, RM1)"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 56244,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.2 i-DTEC AWD (RE6)",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.2 i-DTEC AWD (RE6)"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 56477,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 4WD",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 4WD"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 56765,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.0 AWD (RE5, RM2)",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.0 AWD (RE5, RM2)"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 109764,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 (RM3)",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 (RM3)"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 112198,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 112199,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 4WD",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 4WD"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 122300,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 4WD",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 4WD"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 125363,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 i-VTEC (RM4)",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 i-VTEC (RM4)"
                },
                {
                    "manuId": 45,
                    "modelId": 10180,
                    "carId": 125364,
                    "vehicleTypeDescription": "2.4 i-VTEC 4WD (RM4)",
                    "carName": "HONDA CR-V IV (RM_) 2.4 i-VTEC 4WD (RM4)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "matchingVehiclesCount": 14,
        "dataSource": [
            {
                "dataSourceKey": "vin_filter"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 200
}
```

Comment: What is the API response code?
Can you also log that

Comment: Am getting responde code 200. The thing is when looping through the list of VINs it get the first 2 ones, you can see the vin.json file on the third time I get the the above error which is the title of this thread. I think the problem is with the way data is being stored in json file but I do not know how to go and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't dump multiple times into an opened file. Instead you can create a list and add all the http_responses to the list and dump it once for all.

When you dump multiple times, you're simply inserting multiple dictionaries(json records) into the json file without "," between them and breaking the syntax.

```
try:
    with open('vins.json', 'w') as f:
       http_responses = []
       for vin in VINs:
           response = requests.get(f'https://vindecodervehicle.com/api/v1/?id=xxxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx&vin={vin}')
            response.raise_for_status()
            # access JSOn content
            jsonResponse = response.json()
            http_responses.append(jsonResponse)
            print("Entire JSON response")
            print(jsonResponse)
       #Create the json File.
       json.dump(jsonResponse, http_responses, indent=4)

except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
```

Comment: Hi man, Thx for the feedback. I have made the change as you advice but still got the same error. I even went on putting  ```with open('vins.json', 'w') as f:         #Create the json File.
  json.dump(jsonResponse, http_responses, indent=4)  ```  after the for loops still got the same result. Any other advise would be great thx

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` returns `dict` not json so you don't need `json.dump` after that.

Below is part of your code that you need to change.

```
jsonResponse = response.json()
#Create the json File.
print("Entire JSON response")
print(jsonResponse)
```

Comment: Hi thx for the feedback. I got you man, I just wonder what should I change to? I want to save my data into JSON file. Is there a way in the current scenario that I can do that, or what would you advise me to do? thx again.

Comment: @menotenhanga use `response.text` instead of `response.json()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not try to update to the root of the file directly but instead load the file and update the specific key where you want the data to be added.

```
import requests
import json
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError
#Define The VINs Lists
VINs = ['KPTGOC1FSCP300549', '5J6RM3H53CL015747', 'TDSY61U032248', 'JDAJ210GOO1052908', 'KNAKH812BA7683150', 'jtmbh31v806052793', 'Kmhsh81gdcu864966' ]

try:
    with open('vins.json', 'w') as f:
        my_data = json.load(f)

        for vin in VINs:
            response = requests.get(f'https://vindecodervehicle.com/api/v1/?id=xxxxxxx&key=xxxxxxx&vin={vin}')
            response.raise_for_status()
            # access JSOn content
            jsonResponse = response.json()
            my_data["data"].update(jsonResponse["data"]) 


            #Create the json File.
            json.dump(my_data, f, indent=4)
            print("Entire JSON response")
            print(jsonResponse)
 
except HTTPError as http_err:
    print(f'HTTP error occurred: {http_err}')
except Exception as err:
    print(f'Other error occurred: {err}')
```